# Scrape Dynamic Javascript Websites in Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I am able to read Javascript-data from a website if it is defined as a `<table>` as follows using Python 3 in Google Colab:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html'
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text)[0]
print(df)
```

However, I would similarly like to read data from more complicated Javscript sites directly into Python3 in Google Coolab. This data may not be defined as being in `<table>` format.

For example, I would like to see which dates are 'sold out' and which aren't on the following site:
https://shop.perisher.com.au/lift-ticket-calendar

The difference between available (blue) and sold out (red) dates is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyhFT.jpg)

I have tried doing this using a combination of Selenium, BeautifulSoup and Pandas in Python3 in Colab but haven't been successful.

Comment: you can parse pretty much any website.... I just loaded this page into BeautifulSoup and the javascript built content is not available.   that means you will need to use something like selenium that effectively directs your browser to load then can access the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you analyse the website, the website takes time to load. But once it's loaded, you can analyse the network calls made by the website. The website makes an ajax call to load all the data regarding the soldout dates.

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    "inventoryPoolCode": 8452,
    "duration": 1,
    "quantity": 1,
    "productDate": "9 August, 2020"
}

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
}

res = requests.post("https://shop.perisher.com.au/ProductCalendar/Index", data=payload,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

data = {'soldout':[], 'notsoldout':[]}
for span in soup.find_all("span", class_="grid-item"):
    if "empty" in span["class"]: continue
    date = span["data-date"].strip()
    if "soldout" in span['class']:data['soldout'].append(date)
    else: data['notsoldout'].append(date)

print("Sold Out Dates")
print(data["soldout"])
print("---" * 25)
print("Available Dates")
print(data["notsoldout"])
```

Output:

```
Sold Out Dates
['2020-08-08', '2020-08-09', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-11', '2020-08-13', '2020-08-14', '2020-08-15', '2020-08-16', '2020-08-17', '2020-08-18', '2020-08-20', '2020-08-22', '2020-08-23', '2020-08-29', '2020-08-30']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Available Dates
['2020-08-12', '2020-08-19', '2020-08-21', '2020-08-24', '2020-08-25', '2020-08-26', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-28']
```